# Find the smallest positive integer containing only the digits $2$ and $3$, and at least one of each, that is divisible by both $2$ and $3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Math Help for Algebra I (word problem)
Please help me, thank you!

> Find the smallest positive integer containing only the digits $2$ and $3$, and at least one of each, that is divisible by both $2$ and $3$.

Comment: Do you know how to tell whether a number is divisible by $2$? What about $3$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $n$ such number, by hypothesis $2$ and $3$ divides $n$. This means that $n$ is even and since $n$ only can have digits $2$ and $3$, $n$ must end in $2$. On the other the sum of the digits of $n$ must be multiple of $3$. Because sums of numbers $3$ gives us a multiple of $3$, then the sum of numbers $2$ also has to be multiple of $3$. We have $2+2+2=6$, so $3$ is the minimum number of $2$'s we need to have a multiple $3$. Therefore the smallest number is $n=2232$.

Comment: I had misread the question and posted an incorrect answer, then foolishly criticized yours. My mistake. +1

Comment: I using the hypothesis of the problem. Such number only contains digits $2$ and $3$. 132 is not a counterexample.

Comment: see my comment above. I thought you might see my previous comment before I got to change it. Apologies. Still, perhaps it might help a young student to remove the division notation?

Comment: @TheCount ok, don't worry. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's divisible by $2$ the last digit must be and even number.  If the digits are only $2,3$ the last digit must be $2$.

If it is divisible but $3$ the digits must add up to a multiple of $3$.  It has $2$ and $3$.  Those add to $3+2=5$.  That is not divisible by $3$ so we must add a third digit.  If we add a $2$ we get $3+2+2 = 7$ and if we add a $3$ we get $3+2+3=8$.  Neither of those are divisible by $3$ so we must add a third and a fourth digit.

If we add two $2$s, we have $3+2+2+2=9$.  If we add two $3$s we get $3+2+3+3=11$.  If we add a $2$ and a $3$ we get $3+2+3+2=10$.  Only $3+2+2+2 = 9$ is divisible by $3$.

To get a number as small as possible we want as few digits as possible so we want the digits $3,2,2,2$.  The smallest number with those digits is $2223$ but that doesn't end with $2$.

So the smallest number with those digits that ends in $2$ is $2232$.

$2232 = 2*1116$ and $2232 = 3*744$.  This is the smallest such number.